# How to use cat and for-loop in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a shell script that does following and I would like to do this in Dockerfile instead.
Does anyone know how to do this? I was able to do `sed` command, but am not having luck with for-loop.

```
org="$(cat org-template.yml)"

for i in {1..10}
do
   temp=$org
   temp="${temp/ENDPOINT/$endpoint}"
   temp="${temp/AUTH_TOKEN/$access_token}"
   temp="${temp/LABEL_TOKEN/$i}"
   final_template="${final_template}\n${temp}"
done

final_template="${final_template//
/\\n}"

sed "s#ORGANIZATIONREQUESTS#${final_template}#g" ./performance-tests.yml > /tmp//performance-tests.yml
```

Comment: What docker base image (e.g. `FROM  image:...`) are you using for building your new docker image? Show what you have in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution for this kind of problem is to keep the shell script alongside your Dockerfile, and use the `COPY` directive to copy it into the container, then `RUN` it inside.

The only alternative to that would be passing the whole script as properly escaped argument to `bash -c` , and that would just read horribly; you would anyway need to keep `org-template.yml` around in the container, as well. So, honestly, copying both files into the container would both seem the easiest, and best to maintain, solution.

Also, um, that's YAML: I'd recommend you deal with YAML with the appropriate yaml tools, and not with shell replacements and `sed`; the `yq` utility would be a much safer bet to not be hurt later on.